# How is the noun 'mosaic' being used in this sentence?

Tags: nouns

If a landscape is described as ''a 'mosaic' of fields, heathland, villages and hills'', how is 'mosaic' being used here? Adjective? Collective noun?

Comment: It's a [mass noun](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mosaic) used metaphorically — that is, linking the appearance of the landscape to a tiled floor.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, something seems to be structurally wrong with that Oxford Dictionaries entry. “A mosaic of” can never be a mass noun—it is countable. The point-listed definitions under the “[mass noun]” heading should be shifted left and appear as subitems of definition 1, rather than of “[mass noun]”.

Comment: Yes, it did strike me as a bit odd. They may have meant *collective noun*, or it could be a formatting error as you say.

Comment: What other words can you replace mosaic with meaningfully? What is their part of speech?

Comment: It is a mass noun in *the walls and vaults are decorated by marble and mosaic*

Comment: I'd argue that _mosaic_ in the OP is being used as a quasi-mass noun - rather like _confetti_ in the usual sense. Possibly countable, but treated by all rational-minded beings as non-count (apologies to Trading Standards Officers - though I bet none of them has actually counted a boxful). Compare 'I'll have two tomatoes, one onion and 2523 grains of rice, please.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply in sense 3 of the definition of the noun *[mosaic](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=mosaic)*:

> **mosaic**, *n.*: **3.** Something that resembles a mosaic: *a mosaic of testimony from various witnesses.*

Comment: And notice the unnaturalness of _That makes the third mosaic of testimony we've had in court this week_. As I said earlier, a quasi-mass noun in this extended usage. I think it's a bit dangerous using a word in its own definition, however; I'd prefer something along the lines of: **mosaic** n.: 17. Something that resembles a mosaic (senses 11a or 14f) or patchwork quilt: a mosaic of testimony from various witnesses.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I still don’t see how that’s a ‘quasi-mass noun’. A mass noun cannot be counted or paired with an indefinite article; ‘mosaic’ can do both. Rather, it is simply a collective noun. The fact that some collective nouns are less prone to pluralising than others (it is fine to speak of ‘three groups of people’, but you would rarely hear ‘three plethoras of information’ or ‘three motlies of interest groups’) is not really relevant here. The more variegation is implied with the collective noun, the less likely it is to be pluralised; and ‘mosaic’ does precisely imply variegation.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: Downing and Locke start their discussion on mass nouns with: 'In linguistics, a mass noun ... is a noun that refers to some entity as an undifferentiated unit rather than as something with discrete subsets.' The problem with such a semantic definition is that there are situations where it is arguable whether the unity or diversity is more apparent. However, I think that syntactic definitions beg the question. I'm not happy to regard 'plethora' here as a collective noun as 'information' isn't. A _bowl_ of soup? Never. _Patchwork quilt_ is a near-synonym of _mosaic_ here.

Comment: "**mass noun** : a noun characteristically denoting in many languages a homogeneous substance or a concept without subdivisions (as sand, butter, beer, accuracy distinguished from a grain of sand, a pat of butter, a glass of beer, a degree of accuracy), having in this usage in English only the singular form, and preceded in indefinite constructions by _some_ rather than _a_ or _an_ —called also _noncount noun_" contrasted with "**count noun** : a noun that forms a plural and is used with a numeral, with words such as _many_ or _few_, or in English with the indefinite article _a_ or _an_" [MW]

Comment: But the rules don't hold without rationalisations. 'We have achieved an accuracy hitherto only dreamed of.' 'There was an absence of mirth.' *'There was some absence of mirth.' A dismal existence. *Some dismal existence. **Oh**, and I meant to say above: I'm not happy to regard 'plethora' here as a collective noun as 'information' isn't count.

Comment: That is rather a bizarre argument, since ‘information’ as an uncountable mass noun is precisely expected to be preceded by a collective noun. And what on earth is wrong with ‘a bowl of soup’ or ‘a plate of food’?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Nothing wrong with the expressions - but I'm aghast at the classing of 'bowl' or 'plate' (of) as collective nouns. Wikipedia has <<In linguistics, a collective noun is the name of a number (or collection) of people or things taken together and spoken of as one whole. ...>> The _things_ Wikipedia mentions are **count**,  See the long list at http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_collective_nouns_by_subject . Also, 'Collective nouns, a special class, name groups [things] composed of members [usually people].' ( http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/collectivenoun.htm )

Comment: The modern term for the modifiers in '_not much_ activity', _a gallon of_ soup' etc is _compound quantifiers_ . _Box_ is not a collective noun in _a box of chocolates_. http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/quantifiers

Comment: ‎Geoffrey Leech and ‎Jan Svartvik - at http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CHL8Z7Yhu-AC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=%22unit+nouns%22+a+piece+of+paper&source=bl&ots=DTNocZTSO1&sig=pSOboTa3bx-Yo4RXccDqYN5Foeo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SqELUrHvLsXBhAeTj4GgDQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22unit%20nouns%22%20a%20piece%20of%20paper&f=false - label nouns such as the following unit nouns: a piece of paper / a pile of rubbish / a speck of dust / a length of rope / a load of hay / a tin of soup... (see  http://is.akcentcollege.cz/el/AK10/leto2011/AMOR1/um/partitives-Longman_Grammar_of_Spoken_and_Written_English_Biber.txt )